# XSLT Transform: Remove siblings and Parent, Keep XML info, Add new Parent and Sibling

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, transformation

I have an incoming XML file which has lots of data. I'd like to use XSLT to get rid of unwanted data and add new elements:

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <root>
  <child></child>
  <kid id="2">
    <name>abc</name>
    <age>15</age>
  </kid>
  <mykid></mykid>
 </root>**
```

I'd like to transform it to this (Removed the parent and sibling and wrapped it with new Parent ):

```
 **<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <kids>
    <kid id="2">
        <name>abc</name>
        <age>15</age>
    </kid>
 </kids>**
```

Here are the requirements:

1. Remove all siblings and parent of Kid element.
2. Keep all the details of Kid element including attributes and nested elements.
3. Add a new parent.

I'd really appreciate if anyone can write a skeleton of the XSLT file that I can use to transform my xml? Let me know if I am missing out on anything. There is one more thing I'd like to add, I dont know the details of parent or siblings to be removed. I only know the element of interest and the new parent and siblings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, read up on the XSLT [Identity Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) which can be used to copy existing elements and nodes as-is.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Using this means you meet requirement 2 straight-away, and only have to worry about writing templates to cover requirements 1 and 3.

It would be better if you wrote requirement 1 as just "Remove all siblings of the `kid` element". Then, the template to do this, looks like this

```
<xsl:template match="*[kid]/*[not(self::kid)]" />
```

So, `*[kid]` matches the parent of the `kid` element, and `/*[not(self::kid)]` then matches the child elements, except `kid` itself. The template is empty, so the element gets removed (or rather, it doesn't get copied to the output).

Requirement 3 can then be viewed as "Replace parent of `kid` element with `kids`". The template to do this is as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="*[kid]">
    <kids>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </kids>
</xsl:template>
```

And that's it! Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="*[kid]">
        <kids>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </kids>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[kid]/*[not(self::kid)]" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, it worked. I am new to XPath so couldn't even think of building this expression on my own. I appreciate it!!!